# Where to ask questions about online image hosting?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask the following question?

> I'm creating a website, and I want to have the ability for users to
>   upload and view an image. Kind of like stackexchange, when
>   asking/answering a question, you have the ability to insert an image.
>   Stackexchange uses [imgur](http://imgur.com). What do you suggest I use, and are they
>   free? I checked [imgur](http://imgur.com), and I didn't understand what they said
>   about when you have to pay.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ask this question anywhere.

You are asking for recommendations (a list of resources), and these types of questions are largely disallowed across all sites on the network as they do not lead to quality definitive answers. It will also tend to attract answers that are opinion based ("resource x is better than y because I like it better"), and answers that suffer from link rot over time.

Comment: Do you know any other sites I can ask this? (Meaning, not in the stackexchange family.)