# Where to post question regarding website hosting

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask a question about how to optimize a website I am hosting with dropbox to load faster ([techforteachingph.org](http://techforteachingph.org)). This appears to be off topic on almost every site that I can find. Where can I ask this question?

Comment: For specific host, no SE site fits, only that host support forums.

Comment: Well, I'm a bit more open than that. I'd be fine hosting the images elsewhere. The only issue is that elsewhere seems to be equally slow, so I'm just wondering why the site seems so slow to load when other sites can load much more much faster

Comment: So, your question is actually "where can I ask about finding a fast image host"? In that case, I'm afraid the answer is same as [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268855/where-to-ask-questions-about-online-image-hosting)

Comment: if in fact, that is the problem

Comment: See the edit. Anyway, you can try solve this slowness, and use Stack Overflow when getting stuck, though it means much more efforts on your side. Up to you.

Comment: bummer, ok, thanks for the ideas